# OpenStack Quantum Log shows AMQP server on <server>:5672 is unreachable: Socket closed

Tags: openstack, rabbitmq

In an OpenStack Folsom installation, my quantum server logs at /var/log/quantum/server.log shows:

```
2013-02-06 11:51:38     INFO [quantum.openstack.common.rpc.common] Reconnecting to AMQP server on 10.0.0.1:5672
2013-02-06 11:51:38    DEBUG [amqplib] Start from server, version: 8.0, properties: {u'information': u'Licensed under the MPL. See http://www.rabbitmq.com/', u'product': u'RabbitMQ', u'copyright': u'Copyright (C) 2007-2011 VMware, Inc.', u'capabilities': {}, u'platform': u'Erlang/OTP', u'version': u'2.7.1'}, mechanisms: [u'PLAIN', u'AMQPLAIN'], locales: [u'en_US']
2013-02-06 11:51:41    ERROR [quantum.openstack.common.rpc.common] AMQP server on 10.0.0.1:5672 is unreachable: Socket closed. 
Trying again in 30 seconds.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/quantum/openstack/common/rpc/impl_kombu.py", line 469, in reconnect
    self._connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/quantum/openstack/common/rpc/impl_kombu.py", line 446, in _connect
    self.connection.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 154, in connect
    return self.connection
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 560, in connection
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 521, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqplib.py", line 255, in establish_connection
    connect_timeout=conninfo.connect_timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/transport/pyamqplib.py", line 52, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/connection.py", line 144, in __init__
    (10, 30), # tune
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/abstract_channel.py", line 95, in wait
    self.channel_id, allowed_methods)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/connection.py", line 202, in _wait_method
    self.method_reader.read_method()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/amqplib/client_0_8/method_framing.py", line 221, in read_method
    raise m
IOError: Socket closed
```

What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AMQP server in this case refers to RabbitMQ.

The simple answer is that the quantum server can't log into rabbitmq.  Since you're *NOT* getting an "ECONNREFUSED" error, the server is contactable which means that there is most likely a RabbitMQ server running on that IP.

Make sure your RabbitMQ password is correct.  e.g. The Folsom guide says:

```
rabbitmqctl change_password guest password
```

...meaning that the rabbitmq user is 'guest' and the rabbitmq password is 'password'.

This *must* match the username and password listed in /etc/quantum/quantum.conf

```
# IP address of the RabbitMQ installation
rabbit_host = 10.0.0.1
# Password of the RabbitMQ server
rabbit_password = password
# Port where RabbitMQ server is running/listening
# rabbit_port = 5672
# User ID used for RabbitMQ connections
# rabbit_userid = guest
```

(commented-out lines are default)

Comment: A refused connection most likely means that the Rabbit process is not running.

Comment: @ mgorven Is your experience different?  If I stop the RabbitMQ server then I get ECONNREFUSED, whereas for a failed login I get "Socket Closed"

Comment: Sorry, misread your answer -- thought the OP *was* getting a refused connection.

Comment: @mgorven No worries.  I was wondering if I should emphasise the "not".  Clearly I should have! Corrected. :-)